# Windows/Mac Network share unable to delete; 'File open in another program'

Tags: mac-osx, network-share, file-permissions

We have a network share that has a number of 'un-deletable' folders on it.

It is a known issue that on a windows share, it is not advisable for Apple Mac users to create folder structures: even though an Apple machine/User can be bound to a domain, if their Active Directory Object is deleted, it fails to replicate this change across permissions on the domain...

This can be evidenced by checking a folders security/ownership properties, where the owner ID will be a string of nonsensical numbers and letters: the legacy of a deleted apple user.

[image]

The issue we face is that these folders become irremovable, as no matter whom the ownership of the folder is changed to, regardless of access level; we encounter the 'File open in another program'.

It seems impossible to bypass this issue; even renaming it is blocked.

- **There has been some suggestion that a thumbnail file is open in explorer.**
    *Changing view options yields no result*
- **This error is occurring consistently with Apple users, and only Apple users.**
- **The file is, as far as can be ascertained, NOT in use anywhere on the network, on any machines or backup services.**
- **Navigating to the Computer management of the server and checking 'files open reveals that these locked documents are not open anywhere on the network.**
- **The server has been restarted on several occasions**

Comment: `even though an Apple machine/User can be bound to a domain, if their Active Directory Object is deleted, it fails to replicate this change across permissions on the domain` - Windows behaves the same way. `This can be evidenced by checking a folders security/ownership properties, where the owner ID will be a string of nonsensical numbers and letters` - It's not nonsensical. That's the orphaned SID (Security Identifier) of the deleted user object.

Comment: @joeqwerty, if not nonsensical, then unimportant (for troubleshooting this issue, at least). feel free to edit and improve.

Comment: You don't mention what version of Windows is running on the file server, but you can go into Share and Store Management on the file server, select Manage Open Files, and attempt tp close the open files. Barring that, a reboot of the file server should release the file locks.

Comment: File server is all Windows Server 2012 R2. I should point out, these are legacy issues, they've been with us for a long time. Are you suggesting changing ownership on each basis, and then rebooting the file server?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting as a first step to see if any of the files are open/locked from the perspective of Share and Store Management. If they are then try to close them from there. If that doesn't work then try rebooting the server to see if that resolves it. If that also doesn't work then you'll have to resort to other methods.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I'll answer the outcome of the solution you provided in the body of the question..